# Read Only Error on incident form in plugin CRM 2011 Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a problem, which I'm really trying to figure out how I could best solve this. I have read various posts regarding this error and seems you can avoid this by using JavaScript by using:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").setSubmitMode("always");
```

which doesn't work for me or inside the plugin. Now to my problem, I have an update plugin firing on my incident form, which updates some fields. However when I try to resolve the case or cancel it I get the error from my update plugin "The object cannot be updated because it is read-only" I have tried the following and would appreciate if somone could advice me what I'm doing wrong. My code for a plugin I'm registering as SetState on pre-operation against the incident form:

```
SetStateRequest setState = new SetStateRequest(); 
setState.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(); 
setState.EntityMoniker.Id = incidentId; //Id which needs to be resolved/canceld 
setState.EntityMoniker.Name = "statecode"; 
setState.EntityMoniker.LogicalName = "incident"; 
setState.State = new OptionSetValue(); 
setState.Status = new OptionSetValue(); 
 SetStateResponse setStateResponse = (SetStateResponse)service.Execute(setState); }
```

On the state and status I'm quite confused to what value I have to set it to. I'm just getting an error when my incident is on Active and I'm trying to resolve and cancel the case. I would appreciate if someone could help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you supplying values to the OptionSetValue constructor (e.g. new OptionSetValue(1);)?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm. If I'm not wrong than for Active the value is 0 and for Inactive 1, I dont know what the values for Resolved and Canceled are, I looked into the form as well didn't find it inside the form either. But I just need to know if I'm doing the correct thing because it didn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are a few areas of confusion in your post...

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").setSubmitMode("always");
```

This is clientside code and will never have any bearing on the behaviour of your (serverside) plugin. It merely forces an attribute on the form to be submitted whether it has changed or not, during a save. If the record is in a read-only state, it will not change that fact.

I'm not at all clear what you are trying to acheive in your code. You mention that an update plugin is failing; you have posted code which would attempt to set the state of the incident to something (as @glosrob suggests, you are not providing any values in the `OptionSetValue` objects for `State` and `Status` so as you might already know, the code you have posted is invalid); you then state that you have registered your plugin on the `SetState` request. This means that it would fire if the user tries to set the state of the `incident`. Given that your code is itself trying to set the status of the `incident`, I'm not sure that it makes sense...

It sounds like what you want to do is, on update of an `incident`, set certain values. If the incident is in a read-only state, make it readable first, and then update the values. Do you then need to restore the state of the entity to it's former state? It sounds awkward and might perhaps suggest that there is a better way to meet your core requirement.

Maybe start with what you are trying to achieve and we can work from there :)

Comment: Hi Greg, I apologise if there is a confusion in my question above. What I was trying to bring across is that I have an update plugin firing on the incident form. Working all well, doing also what it supposed to be doing. BUT when I try to resolve the case I get this error of "The object cannot be updated because it is read-only", and hence my question is if it has to do anything with the state of the incident as it is the only read-only field on my form ? Do I need to update it seperately? Thanks.

Comment: No need to apologise :) Question for you: should your plugin fire when the incident is being resolved?

Comment: I believe so, because my update plugin doesn't make any changes onto the state and status of the inncident form, when it is resolved and hence that's why I think I'm getting this error...

Comment: But is it a requirement that the other fields get updated, even if it when the record is resolved (or already resolved)? If you don't _need_ to update update those fields at that point then this becomes easier...

Comment: Hi greg, yes not further updates need to be made after the case is resolved or canceld I just want the form to be sumbitted as it is. Like saying before the update plugin already makes all the neccessary updates beforhand, right now I'm just having trouble to submit the form, when resolving or cancling the form.

Comment: ok I've certainly seen cases where updates are fired for state changes. perhaps you could add an if block at the start if your code:  `if(((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Attributes.contains("statecode")){return;}`

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks I just tried your code. But when I place it in my update plugin it doesn't make any update now. I think what is happening is that every time I try to resolve/cancel the case my update plugin fires, and because of the state change I get this error. Is there a way of somehow filtering of that specific field on update? So that the whole form does get updated but ignores the state of the state field...

Comment: I don;t feel like i've got a good handle on what should and shouldn't be happening but to address your most recent point, I guess you could adjsut the code I added above to prevent the plugin from processing under certain conditions. For example: `// don't run code if incident state is included, unless incident is still active
if(((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Attributes.contains("statecode") && ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Attributes["statecode"] != 0){return;}`

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your reply, yup you got that one spot on. What I did is get the value of the option set value for the staecode, and make sure update is only done when incident is active (Value == 0). As you mentiones above, such an easy solution to such a stupid bug argh :-) Thanks Again For Your Effort.

Comment: No problem - can you mark this as answer if this is what resolved your issue? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove

```
setState.EntityMoniker.Name = "statecode";
```

from your code. This field `Name` has other purpose.
Also, you should add

```
setState.State.Value = 1;
setState.Status.Value = -1;
```

Comment: totally. well spotted paramosh.